# Oracle - find Nearest Lines for point

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, oracle11g

There is one table having structure -

```
table rt_lines {
  line SDO_Geometry,
  start_point SDO_Geometry,
  end_point SDO_Geometry,
};
```

Lets say my route is `A-B-C-D-E-F`

In table, records will be stored in following way.

```
line  start_point end_point 
A-B      A           B
B-C      B           C
C-D      C           D
D-E      D           E
E-F      E           F
```

Given - I have one location point lets say L1.
And then I need to find out the nearest point from L1 using Oracle function SDO_NN. Lets say nearest point is B then I want to fetch two records i.e 
A-B & B-C.

How can I achieve this in Oracle using in built functions?

Got the solution!!

**Solution** -

I have used following query to find lines. For example lines A-B & B-C if we consider here, B is nearest to point L1.

```
SELECT l.* FROM rt_lines l WHERE
SDO_NN(l.start_point,MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,8307,NULL,MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,2,1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(L1.x, L1.y)), 'sdo_batch_size=0 ', 1) = 'TRUE' AND ROWNUM=1

UNION ALL

SELECT  l.* FROM rt_lines l WHERE
SDO_NN(l.end_point,MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,8307,NULL,MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,2,1),MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(L1.x, L1.y)),'sdo_batch_size=0 ', 1) = 'TRUE' AND ROWNUM=1);
```

Comment: I may need more information, What is your rute? an array, a table, a string, a line?

Comment: Isnt clear what you want or your desire output. Because looks like you already have it all.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - rt_lines is table where we stored route info.

Comment: Again isnt clear what are you asking.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza -  I want sql query which returns records having line A-B & B-C if B is the nearest point to L1. And in oracle we can find nearest geometry using SDO_NN function please refer this.

Comment: For future reference you should read [**Need an Answer? Actually, No ... You Need a Question**](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx) I could try to guess what is your question but wouldnt waste my time if you cant take proper time to describe the problem

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Thanks for you time!! I constructed sql query which returns me the two lines of point which is nearest to point L1.